# How to delete a indiviudal collection view cell via button inside that cell using a tag

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview, tags, uicollectionviewcell

My code below removes a label from a uicollectionview. However the labal is just remove and I would like the whole cell to be removed. My code below is the button controlling these actions. I am using core data on the label. I also added a before and after pitcure of the desired result.

[image]
[image]

```
         var itemName : [Item] = []
    @objc func elete(_ sender:UIButton){
    let itemName1 = itemName[sender.tag]

    itemName1.atBATS?.removeAll()
    itemName1.image?.removeAll()



    collectionView.reloadData()

}
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting that big white space? Or are you wanting to have the cells rearrange to make up for the now missing cell?

Comment: You need to delete the item from the datasource and then reload colletionview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delete the item from the dataSource/core data and then reload the collection view.

```
@objc func elete(_ sender:UIButton){
    itemName.remove(at: sender.tag) // this removes from array, but you should also remove from core data.

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. However. I want to presently delete that single entry from core data. When I reload the class. What I deleted reappears exactly the same.

Comment: What code are you using to delete the entry from CoreData?  Without deleting from core data, you'll most likely keep seeing the data (depending on how you're setting the itemName)

Comment: Your right. There is no line of code I have currently deleting any core data. I am not saving the context .